# How to extract color features of an image in R

Tags: r, colors

I'd like to do some image feature extraction in R. At the moment I am working with the EBImage package. I can get a RGB-histogramm with the hist-function, but can I also get a Lab-Histogramm? Further I also would like to store the data of the histogramms (the distribution of the pixel intensity). How is this possible? And is it possible to extract a color-correlogram of an image in R? If yes, how can I do this?
Thanks a lot!
Here is the code I have done so far (with comments):

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R") 
biocLite() 
biocLite("EBImage") 
library(EBImage) 
image1 <- readImage('C:/Users/Inalei/Pictures/Image1.JPG')
image2 <- readImage('C:/Users/Inalei/Pictures/Image2.JPG') 
image3 <- readImage('C:/Users/Inalei/Pictures/Image3.JPG')

hist1 <- hist(image1) #hist1 is empty
hist2 <- hist(image2) #hist2 is empty
hist3 <- hist(image3) #hist3 is empty

library(corrgram)
corrgram(image1) #Error in slot(x, ".Data")[, sapply(x, is.numeric), drop = FALSE] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Comment: Please add some reproducible code showing what you have done so far, which will help people answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

I've just updated EBImage development version to facilitate the extraction of the image histogram data. Now the `hist` method invisibly returns a named list of objects of class "histogram" corresponding to the red, green, and blue channels. For example, to access the distribution of green pixel intensities you can use

```
hist1 <- hist(image1)
hist1$green
```

To use this feature, either install EBImage from sources

```
library(devtools)
install_github("Bioconductor-mirror/EBImage")
```

or wait until the binaries of EBImage version 4.13.5 are available from the package landing page at https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/3.3/bioc/html/EBImage.html.

Re your question about the Lab color space: unfortunately, currently we don't  support it.

To make a correlogram across the color channels, first construct a data frame containing columns of pixel values of each channel

```
channels = sapply(c("red", "green", "blue"),
  function(ch) as.vector(channel(x, ch)),
  simplify = FALSE)
channels = as.data.frame(channels)
```

and then pass is to the `corrgram` function

```
corrgram(channels)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. It was working fine after the update. Just to get a color correlogram (like it is described here: http://www.cs.cornell.edu/rdz/Papers/ecdl2/spatial.htm & http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~rdz/papers/huang-cvpr97.pdf) I need to find another solution. My objective is also (like in the references) to measure the distance of the feature vectors of images to find similar ones in a database.